# Update 1st row headers with info from the 2nd row for csv file using python

Tags: python, pandas, etl

I have this dataframe in a csv that it's received like this:

[image]

And my goal here is to incorporate the second row in the headers row to the first blank cell to the right, in a way that my end result would be like this:

[image]

quite confuse in how to create a solution for this, any thoughts in how I could tackle this issue?

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

csv_file_name= 'test.csv'

file = open(csv_file_name)
csvreader = csv.reader(file)

df = pd.DataFrame(csvreader)

df.head(10)

0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ... 17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26
0   ï»¿"Scenario"   Annee   Version Client  Destination Source  Activite    Organisation    Periode Currency    ... None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
1   GMVE_STE    GMVE7190    GMVE_ICO    GMVE_   GMVI_   GMV_    GMA_    RCH RBC TFP ... None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
2   F1_U    FY22    VD  Client  BR_IFRS GLOBAL_SOURCE   U10 0898_   JAN KEURO   ...     4.998999999999796                               4.998999999999796
3   F1_U    FY22    VD  Client  BR_IFRS GLOBAL_SOURCE   U10 0898_   FEB KEURO   ...     40.29999999999927                               40.29999999999927
4   F1_U    FY22    VD  Client  BR_IFRS GLOBAL_SOURCE   U10 0898_   MAR KEURO   ...     -19.26100000000042                              -19.26100000000042
5   F1_U    FY22    VD  Client  BR_IFRS GLOBAL_SOURCE   U10 0898_   APR KEURO   ...     -26.03800000000047                              -26.03800000000047
6   F1_U    FY22    VD  Client  BR_IFRS GLOBAL_SOURCE   U10 0898_   MAY KEURO   ...     324.9980000000014                               324.9980000000014
7   F1_U    FY22    VD  Client  BR_IFRS GLOBAL_SOURCE   U10 0898_   JUN KEURO   ...     1.818989403545856e-12                               1.818989403545856e-12
8   F1_U    FY22    VD  Client  BR_IFRS GLOBAL_SOURCE   U10 0898_   JUL KEURO   ...     0                               0
9   F1_U    FY22    VD  Client  BR_IFRS GLOBAL_SOURCE   U10 0898_   AUG KEURO   ...     0                               0
10 rows × 27 columns
```

I need to use the csv.reader because with pandas option for reading csv's I get a error

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 11 fields in line 2, saw 17
```

I am not able to share the csv, since I receive it already with the commas being separated, and everything that I copy here it's transformed in picture

Answer (score 1):

I think this might work :

```
    row_1 = list(df.iloc[0])
    df.columns = list(df.columns) + row_1
```

it would be nice to have an example of dataframe so people can try it out!

Comment: Thanks! Your idea worked! I will post my solution

Answer (score 1):

using @grymlin idea, I was able to work something out that does what I want:

```
row_1 = list(df.iloc[0])
row_1_upd = list(filter(None,row_1))
row_2 = list(df.iloc[1])
row_2_upd = list(filter(None,row_2))

new_cols = row_1_upd+row_2_upd

len(new_cols)
28

len(df.columns)
27

list_df_col = list(df.columns)

for i in range(len(list_df_col)):
    list_df_col[i]=new_cols[i]

df.columns = list_df_col
df = df.iloc[2:]

df.head()

ï»¿"Scenario"   Annee   Version Client  Destination Source  Activite    Organisation    Periode Currency    ... GMA_    RCH RBC TFP TFEX    LTSR_   TFS TBDT    FSI TCD
2   F1_U    FY22    VD  Client  BR_IFRS GLOBAL_SOURCE   U10 0898_   JAN KEURO   ...     4.998999999999796                               4.998999999999796
3   F1_U    FY22    VD  Client  BR_IFRS GLOBAL_SOURCE   U10 0898_   FEB KEURO   ...     40.29999999999927                               40.29999999999927
4   F1_U    FY22    VD  Client  BR_IFRS GLOBAL_SOURCE   U10 0898_   MAR KEURO   ...     -19.26100000000042                              -19.26100000000042
5   F1_U    FY22    VD  Client  BR_IFRS GLOBAL_SOURCE   U10 0898_   APR KEURO   ...     -26.03800000000047                              -26.03800000000047
6   F1_U    FY22    VD  Client  BR_IFRS GLOBAL_SOURCE   U10 0898_   MAY KEURO   ...     324.9980000000014                               324.9980000000014
```